# angular 5 dropdown retain values

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I am tying to generate some fields on the click of a button. The fields are generated fine but the dropdown in the generated fields are not retaining the values selected. They are pushed to the array but the values are not shown in the form. The code is as follows.

app.component.html

---

```
<form #formRef="ngForm">
  <div *ngFor="let test of mytest; let in=index" class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="form-group"  >
        <select  name="fe[in]" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="test.name" >
          <option  *ngFor="let f of fields" [value]="f">{{f}}</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <select name="ty[in]" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="test.type"> 
          <option  *ngFor="let ty of types" [value]="ty">{{ty}}</option>
        </select><br>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="test.placeholder" name="name{{in}}" class="form-control" #name="ngModel" required />
        <br>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="test.values" name="name{{in}}" class="form-control" #name="ngModel" />
      </div>
      <br />
  </div>
  <button [disabled]="!formRef.form.valid" (click)="add([in])">Add input</button>
</form>
<br />
<br />
{{ mytest | json}}
```

app.component.ts

---

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { test } from './test';

  @Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  mytest: test[] = [];
  fields: string[] = ['First Name','Last Name','Email Address','Address1 ','Address2 ','City','Postal Code','Province']
  types: string[] = ['text','email','password','dropdown','radio button','check boxes'];

  add(val) {

    this.mytest.push({name: '',type: '',placeholder:'',values:''});

  }
}
```

Comment: looks fine to me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-dropdown-retain-values?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: @MarcelHoekstra it is pushing the values fine but the dropdowns show empty when you add another instance of the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has to do with the control name:

```
<select name="ty[in]"
```

change this to: e.g.

```
<select [name]="'f' + in"
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-dropdown-retain-values)